# Logging into my mjpg-stream from an android application

Tags: android, mjpeg

I have an mjpg-stream running locally and port forwarded on port 8080 for a project i am currently working on. I have decided to adapt [this application](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview/src) to suit my own needs.

I can access the stream when there is no username or password, however because i am port forwarding i have decided to protect the stream and this means that i need to now add a username and password field to the application to authenticate the access and i don't know how to do this.

[This is what the login prompt looks like in a browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4LlY.png)

Any help would be appreciated :)